# Don't want any tab widget selected in tab host <android>

Tags: android

Can anyone please help to solve this : I have 5 tab widgets in my TabHost; when I start my TabActivity extended class, the fist tab-widget is selected by default, but I don't want to select any until user click on one.

I also tried setting the selected tab to -1, but it's not working.

Please help me if you know the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra `Tab`, as your first tab, and make that tab `invisible`. When you create the first time your `TabActivity` select that tab.( `setCurrentTab(0)`);